# Display price depending on JSON data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I'm having two JSON data where one has null price and another one has some price.If i select the particular product it has to evaluate from JSON and show the correct price when I pull the first one, if I select the second one where it has no price it has to display a normal button there. I think it can be achieved using *ngIf by still stuck in logics.

```
HTML 
    <h2 class="py-2 new-price">${{product?.newPrice}}</h2> 


JSON 1
    { 
        "id": 1,
        "name": "SolidWorks to Revit Exporter",
        "images": [
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/keyboard/1-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/keyboard/1-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/keyboard/1-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/keyboard/2-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/keyboard/2-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/keyboard/2-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/keyboard/3-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/keyboard/3-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/keyboard/3-big.png"
            }
        ],
        "oldPrice": null,
        "newPrice": null,
        "discount": null,
        "ratingsCount": 4,
        "ratingsValue": 350,
        "description": "Revit Exporter for SolidWorks is a data exchange tool which creates Parametric Revit families/Projects from SolidWorks parts and assemblies. Exports the SolidWorks model into a BXf file, the exported BXF file is then imported into BIM/Revit platform. All parametric information including geometry, parameters, units, materials etc. will be converted. The tool supports various industry specific requirements like geometric simplification, parameter data exchange",
        "availibilityCount": 5,
        "color": ["#5C6BC0","#66BB6A","#90A4AE"],
        "size": ["S","M","L", "XL"],
        "weight": 150,
        "categoryId": 100
    }
JSON 2
    { 
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Creo to Revit Exporter",
        "images": [
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/pc/1-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/pc/1-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/pc/1-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/pc/2-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/pc/2-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/pc/2-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/pc/3-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/pc/3-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/pc/3-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/pc/4-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/pc/4-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/pc/4-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/pc/5-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/pc/5-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/pc/5-big.png"
            },
            {
                "small": "assets/images/products/pc/6-small.png",
                "medium": "assets/images/products/pc/6-medium.png",
                "big": "assets/images/products/pc/6-big.png"
            }
        ],
        "oldPrice": 2510,
        "newPrice": 99,
        "discount": 15,
        "ratingsCount": 8,
        "ratingsValue": 800,
        "description": "Creo to Revit Exporter is a data exchange tool which creates Parametric Revit families/Projects from Creo parts and assemblies. Exports the Creo model into a Bxf file, the exported Bxf file is then imported into Revit platform. All parametric information including geometry, parameters, units, materials etc.. will be converted. The tool supports various industry specific requirements like geometric simplification, parameter data exchange",
        "availibilityCount": 3,
        "color": ["#1D1D1D","#DADADA","#597087"],
        "size": ["24''","28''","32''"],
        "weight": 9550,
        "categoryId": 100
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `||` for that like `product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice`

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/display-price-depending-on-json-data-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

```
<h2 class="py-2 new-price" *ngIf="product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice">${{product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice}}</h2>

<button  *ngIf="!(product?.newPrice || product2?.newPrice)">Display Button</button>
```

Comment: I need to display a button there where the price is null @krishnaRathore

Comment: you can use *ngIf for that

Comment: I know that! Can you please set up the logic @Krishna Rathore

Comment: Hi @Ajay_Venkatesh I have update link plz check
if product_1  and product_2 price are null then display button right